# unwind segue not work

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I add a an action method to view controller and Ctrl-Drag the button to Exit icon in storyboard,and the unwind segue is created successfully.But when I touch the button, the unwind segue doesn't work(the current scene doesn't navigate to original scene) and the action method isn't triggered.I don't know why.

here is the action method

```
@interface HMCViewController2 : UIViewController
-(IBAction)return:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue;
@end

@implementation HMCViewController2
...
-(IBAction)return:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue{

}

@end
```

I upload the [project](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0Ygk57VnimYQ3JoWW9RVUk2dlk/edit?usp=sharing) to google drive.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You have put your unwind segue code in the wrong viewController. It should be located in the controller you wish to unwind TO, not the controller you are returning FROM.